# Creating a good interface for functions which works with paths

Tags: c, path, cross-platform

I have functions which get file path as their input argument. This functions are cross platform. Functions support both unicode and regular file paths. What is the best interface for this functions, know I have 2 chooses:

1. make two version of each function `FunctionW` and `FunctionA` as in `WinAPI`.
2. make one version which will get `char *` as input argument, but this string must be in `UTF8` format.

Which one is better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the rest of your code and how you're going to use them. There is no correct answer here - try to approximate the time it will take you to write, to use and to maintain each one of the options, and try to take the one where it's easier.
You should also consider the difference between `FunctionA` and `FunctionW`. If the difference isn't big, then you can likely use a single inner helper function that both of them will call, and so the extra time for writing and maintaining a second function is minimal. If it is, consider how tough it would be (if at all) to convert strings to `UTF8` for the 2nd option you presented.

Comment: In fact, `FunctionA` and `FunctionW` will call the same `FunctionUTF8`, the only thing they do is, converting `char *` or `wchar_t *` to `utf8`. Which means that, in the first case(2 functions), my function will convert input string to `utf8` itself, while in the second case, user must convert string to `utf8` and then pass it to my function.

Comment: Since converting to utf8 is something that always has to be done before calling this function, I think it would be wise to do this for the user, this way you also save code duplication.  
As a rule (usually), whenever something needs to always happen before calling some function, make it part of the function, or better yet - part of a function that will later call the first function.